# How to fill second array from the first one using do while loop in java?

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

So basically my problem is this:

I have an array (the first array, array A) which has 20 elements with integer values from 0 to 20 (they can be random) like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 

1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4
```

I need to make another array with 40 elements (the second array, array B) which has the same values as the first array, but the catch is that the values of first array are used in second array, but in this pattern:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
6 6 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
5 5 6 6 1 1 2 2 3 3
4 4 5 5 6 6 1 1 2 2
```

Basically, the second array's values from the start are:

```
B[0] = A[0]
B[1] = A[0]
B[2] = A[1]
B[3] = A[1]
etc.
```

and I need to achieve it by using do while loop.

```
     do {
        i++;
        B[i] = A[i];
        if(i>1) {
            B[i] = A[i-1];
        }
        System.out.print("\t" + B[i]+ " ");
        }
        while(i < 20);
```

Right now I am stuck with this, I can't figure out the part which states how the second array(B) is filled out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to a for:

```
 int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4};
 int[] B = new int[A.length * 2];
 int index_a = 0; 
 int index_b = 0;
 do {
      B[index_b++] = B[index_b++] = A[index_a++];
 }
 while(index_a < A.length);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(B));
```

You need two initial condition in this case `index_a`; and `index_b` the operation that you want to do

```
     B[index_b++] = B[index_b++] = A[index_a++];
```

and the loop condition `index_a < A.length`.

This  `B[index_b++] = B[index_b++] = A[index_a++];` is the same as

```
B[index_b] = A[index_a];
index_b++;
B[index_b] = A[index_a];
index_b++;
index_a++;
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried every answer on this question, and it works! Thanks you guys for your invested time in this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like this:

```java
int[] A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4};
int[] B = new int[A.length * 2];
int i = 0;

do {
    int index = 2 * i;
    B[index] = A[i];
    B[index + 1] = A[i];
    i++;
} while(i < A.length);
```

What you do here is map each element from A to `2x` and `2x + 1` of its index. Then you may fill in the "gaps" like you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a do-while loop that does exactly what you asked.

```
int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] B = new int[A.length*2];

int i = 0;
do {
    // Iterates through 0 & 1, then 2 & 3, etc.
    B[i*2] = A[i];
    B[i*2+1] = A[i];
    i++;
} while (i < A.length);

for (int num : B) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", num);
}
```

This prints `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4`.